# PHP scandir() and htmlentities(): issues with charset and/or special characters

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using [jqueryFileTree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) to show a directory listing on the server with download links to the files in the directory.
Recently I've run into an issue with files which contain special characters:

- test.pdf : works fine
- tést.pdf : does not work (notice the é - acute accent - in the filename)

When debugging the php connector of jqueryFileTree, I see it's doing a scandir() of the directory passed via $_GET, and then looping over each file/dir of the directory.
Before parsing the filename into the url, the script seems to correctly perform a htmlentities() over the file name.
The problem seems to be that this htmlentities($file) call just returns an empty string, which according to the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) this can be the case when the input string contains an invalid code unit within the given encoding. However i tried passing the charset implicitly by calling:

```
$file = htmlentities($file,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

But this also returns an empty string.

If I call:
$file = htmlentities($file,ENT_IGNORE,'UTF-8');
The e acute character is just dropped (so tést.pdf becomes tst.pdf)

When debugging my php script with xdebug I can see the source string contains an unknown character (looks like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Replacement_character.svg)).

So I'm quite at my wits end here to find the solution for this.
Any help would be welcome.

FYI:

- The charset of my page is UTF-8 (specified in metadata)
- The file is stored on a windows 2003 fileserver and scandir() is executed with the UNC path (e.g. //fileserver/sharename/sourcedir)
- The default encoding in my php.ini is set to UTF-8
- The webserver & PHP 5.4.26 are running on a windows 2008 R2 server

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My best guess is that the filename itself isn't using UTF-8. Or at least `scandir()` isn't picking it up like that.

Maybe `mb_detect_encoding()` can shed some light?

```
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($filename));
```

If not, try to guess the encoding (CP1252 or ISO-8859-1 would be my first guess) and convert it to UTF-8, see if the output is valid:

```
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($filename, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252'));
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($filename, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1'));
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($filename, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15'));
```

Or using `iconv()`:

```
var_dump(iconv('WINDOWS-1252', 'UTF-8', $filename));
var_dump(iconv('ISO-8859-1',   'UTF-8', $filename));
var_dump(iconv('ISO-8859-15',  'UTF-8', $filename));
```

Then when you've figured out which encoding is actually used, your code should look somewhat like this (assuming CP1252):

```
$filename = htmlentities(mb_convert_encoding($filename, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I got as far as trying iconv() but only tried 'WINDOWS-1251' and not the 1252 variant, go figure :-) I was able to fix my script thanks to this answer, enjoy the bounty :)

Comment: Please add a comma after "mb_convert_encoding( $filename, 'UTF-8', ..." or you will get an error. I suggested an edit but I had to add other characters in order to validate it (because edits should be 6 characters at least)

Comment: dont work for me , please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119920/how-to-use-utf8-character-in-path-address-for-scandir-php